# currently logged in user account disappeared after removing a different user

Tags: command-line, permissions, login, configuration, users

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Thinkpad Extreme Gen 2, with Nvidia Drivers 450 from the default repos (if that changes anything)

Was doing some development in Objective-C on another user (referring to as izder456dev from now on). I was doing this because the script that sets environment variables doesn't work on my main shell, fish. So, I created another user with `sudo adduser izder456dev` and gave the izder456dev user the login shell of zsh with `sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh izder456dev`.

I've since deleted the user izder456dev (followed this tutorial : https://linoxide.com/linux-command/how-delete-remove-user-ubuntu/), and now I cannot see my main user in the GDM3 login screen ( I have to type in the username ). Once logged in to my main user account, I go to the user settings in the settings app and no user shows up (but im logged in as a user?).

How can I get my user to show up in GDM3 and the User Panel in settings so I can log in normally?

Comment: What is the numerical uid of the user?

Comment: the uid is 1000. the full output of the `id` command is `uid=1000(izder456) gid=1000(izder456) groups=1000(izder456),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare),1002(dev)`

Comment: OK thanks - that rules out GDM treating it as a system account based on uid < 1000. Not sure what the other reasons might be.

Comment: Thanks for asking and allowing me to answer. You may want to re-type command or re-booting the system.

Comment: Mohammad, this was asked two years ago. Please, it’s been solved. I just reinstalled with a more compatible distro. My user had full access but my hybrid graphics auto config got in the way of logging in.